# Store data in arraylist and save it next time I start the program

Tags: java

I am really stuck at the moment, what I am doing wrong.

I have made this program that read some member names and member lastnames from a file and put it into an arraylist.

Then I made a scanner so I can write a name and lastname, and it check if the name and lastname contains in the arraylist. And if the names are in the arraylist, then I can enter a number to that person.
It is working, the number I am entered and is on the right place in the arraylist.

But next time I runs the program, and I choose another person it has not been saving the values in the arraylist how can I do that? So everytime I run the program it has been saving the information that I have enter.

This is the code that I have been making, I am a newbie on this.

```
    import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
   public class result
{

getList list = new getList();
Scanner input;
Scanner result;
PrintStream output;


public ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(list.showListToArray());       




public result() throws Exception
{

    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    result = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = input.next();
    String lastName = input.next();


           if(resultList.contains(name) && resultList.contains(lastName))
           {



              System.out.print(name + lastName + "Enter his result ");

              String bestResult = result.next();

              int position = resultList.indexOf(lastName)+1;

              resultList.add(position, bestResult);                  


            }

            System.out.print(resultList);    
}



}
```

Comment: where do you save the information? Database or in file? I see no relevant code...

Comment: If your program gets terminated, then everything in the memory is gone... You won't get past values in the arraylist. Either you have to save the data in a file or DB before termination and load the saved data into the arraylist on startup

Comment: Is it a web application..?? Are you saying that every time you get back from the bean class you are losing the data..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue called [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29). It's a really simple issue, and in your case, it's a really nice way to get into the practise.

**What you need to do**

At the moment, you're taking an input from the user, and you're adding it to an `ArrayList`. This is fine, but when the program is closed, your `ArrayList` will get destroyed by the Garbage Collector, and the data inside of it will be lost. What you need to do is write these values to an external file, we'll call it `test.txt`.

**How to do it**

The principle is simple. You write things to a file that you want to keep, and you read them when you want them.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.txt")));

String stuffToWrite = "Hello";

writer.write(stuffToWrite);

writer.close();
```

This will now print `"Hello"` into the file named `test.txt`.

And reading from it is also very straight forward.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));

String content = reader.readLine();

// content now contains "Hello".
```

Comment: Wouldn't using java serialisation be easier? Especially since the OP just has a list of strings.

Comment: It appears that OP hasn't yet learnt about the principles surrounding persistence. I thought it was best that OP implements their own code, so they understand the foundation of the problem.

Comment: Thanks christopfer I will try this

Comment: But when I insert a new number, it is overwriting the file when I do this

Comment: Then you need to open the reader in append mode. Have a read about append mode and you'll understand!